# Random 7 digit number getting printed in front of printf statement in output terminal while taking input from user in vs code

Tags: c, printf

Random 7 digit number getting printed in front of `printf` statement in output terminal while taking input from user in VS Code

[image]

Comment: Please post your code and the errors as text, not as image. Read https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode to understand why.

Comment: many compilers have Warning options to detect these errors

Answer (score 4):

You have a redundant `%d` in that `printf`. Since you aren't providing an argument to match it, `printf` just takes whatever happens to be on the stack, and you get that seemingly random number. To make a long story short - lose the `%d` and you should be fine:

```c
printf("Enter any number\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think `printf("Enter any number %d\n");` does?

Specifically, what do you think the `%d` does?

#### That is the answer to your problem